# libVLCNet player positioning (without showing the movie begining) when opening new video

Tags: c#, libvlc

I'm looking at libvlcnet 0.4.0.0 "SimplePlayer" example from http://sourceforge.net/p/libvlcnet/wiki/Home/ and I want to ask if is it possible to to open new file and play it from predefined position without needing to play the start of the movie? I use something like this:

```
        LibVlcInterop.libvlc_media_player_play(descriptor);
        LibVlcInterop.libvlc_media_player_pause(descriptor);
        LibVlcInterop.libvlc_media_player_set_position(descriptor, (float)0.8);
        int res = LibVlcInterop.libvlc_media_player_play(descriptor);
```

When trying to play new file user can notice small fraction of the beginning of the movie.

How can I position player to particular area after I load new file without showing small portion of the beginning of movie?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about that particular library, but you can do this generally by passing "media options" before you play the media. To do this use the LibVLC API function `libvlc_media_add_option`.

If you can do this in that library, then you can specify a start time and/or an end time - but it has to be specified as seconds rather than as a percentage position.

The options you would pass to the API function would be:

```
:start-time=30
:stop-time=60.5
```

You can actually pass fractional seconds as shown in the stop-time example.

When I do this, I do not notice any flash of content showing the beginning of the movie but I suppose that still might happen on some platforms or with some types of media.